# Help in hector slam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can any one tell me what are the steps i should do to build map using hector_slam?
I already applied this [hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData), but did not show any map
Am using fuerte

regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55273/help-in-hector-slam/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial normally works for everyone. Are you sure you have configured your rviz display correctly? The "fixed frame" should be "map" and you should have a active map display showing the "/map" topic.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1